# find values from a given array

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

I have some temperature measurements that are recorded throughout a water column:

```
depth = 0.2211:0.26:26;
temp = 1 + (30-1)*(rand(1,length(depth)));
```

where the depth is not continuous. I would like to create a profile of the temperature at depth increments of 0.5 m. To achieve this I firstly create an array of evenly spaced points from the minimum to the maximum depths of the measurements:

```
newD = min(depth):0.5:max(depth);
```

Next I would like to obtain the temperature from 'temp' at each of these new depths, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate

`newTemp = interp1(depth,temp,newD)`

You may want to experiment the with 4th input to `interp1`, check the documentation.